# Login to a secure site from webview and pass a url to HttpUrlConnection to download - Error 403

Tags: android, webview, httpurlconnection

In my app, I have a webview implementing a downloadlistener. The download listener uses a HttpUrlConnection to download a file with the given url. 
I am having issues when I login  to some secure site, say dropbox.com (from my webview) and then try to download some file. I get error 403 HTTP_FORBIDDEN.

Is it because the session held by the Webview is unknown to the HttpUrlConnection opened by the downloadlistener?

How do I share the same session (share sessionID? cookie? httpclient? ) between my webview and the HttpUrlConnection?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DownloadListener is one of the more annoying interfaces in android (why they can't just pass you the stream is beyond me, it has to have already made a request to get the info to pass to DonwloadListener) Anyway, yes, your HttpUrlConnection knows nothing about any cookies currently in play in the webview. You can usee the `CookieManager` to get details about cookies from the WebView and then add them to your HttpUrlConnection based request, something like this,

```
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
if (cookie != null) req.setRequestProperty("cookie", cookie);
```

Comment: All worked fine when my webview and downloading function is all in the same app, say App1. Now, I moved just the downloading part from App1 to an independent service (a whole new app in itself, say App2), and passed the cookie string from App1  to the downloadservice in App2. Now, the HttpUrlConnection complains about SSLHandShakeException, cert.CertificationException etc. Firstly, I do not know if it is right at all to pass cookie info from 1 app to another but I am curious to know why it broke with the same cookie string but a different app. thanks!

Comment: just found out that the above problem happens only in the device and not in the emulator. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it because the session held by the Webview is unknown to the HttpUrlConnection opened by the downloadlistener?
```

Probably.

Why don't you use the same `WebView` to download the file after login?

```
myWebView.loadUrl(downloadURL);
```